# Having difficulty plotting a function, its first derivative, and its indefinite integral on the same plot

Tags: python, plot, anaconda, numerical-integration, derivative

I'm trying to replicate a plot in Python that I've made previously in Matlab, where three functions are plotted on the same xy axes.

A red line represents the function y=1/(1+(x^2)), a blue line represents its first derivative, and a green to represent its indefinite integral.

I'm having problems in two areas:

1) I've tried a few different ways, but I've been unable to set the y axis range to be -1.5 to 1.5.

2) I'm receiving the error "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension" when trying to plot the third line, the integral.

As you can see in the code below, I'm actually using the definite integral from -infinity to infinity, as I also couldn't work out how to write the indefinite integral. So any assistance you can provide here would also be helpful.

```
from scipy.misc import derivative as deriv
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integ
import pylab as pyl

f = lambda x : 1 / (1 + x**2)

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)

d = deriv(f,x)

i = integ.quad(f,-np.inf,np.inf)

pyl.plot(x,f(x),'r-')
pyl.plot(x,d,'b-')
pyl.plot(x,i,'g-')
pyl.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
pyl.show()
```

The graph I'm getting from the code displays the correct red and blue functions, but the y axis is obviously not quite right, and the green function doesn't display (due to the error mentioned earlier)

I'm very grateful for any assistance anybody can offer.

Comment: 1. You already import `numpy` so you don't need the full `pylab`, just import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.
2. You compute the integral of a function which returns a single number (plus an error estimate in this case, see [quad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad)), how do you expect to plot that?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be misusing `scipy.integrate.quad`. This function gives the definite integral between two values. From the docs:

```
>>> f = lambda x,a : a*x
>>> y, err = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1, args=(1,))
>>> y
0.5
```

So this returns the value of the integral and the error on that value in a tuple. You are trying to plot that tuple against the `x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)` array. Clearly the size of tuple and the array don't match, so you cannot plot the data.

If you wanted to plot a straight line at the value of the integral for all the specified X coordinates, you can use:

```
pyl.hlines(i[0],x[0],x[-1])
```